# Joining 2 dynamic ranges using {} operator in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 tables resulting from the query formulas

**formula1**

```
=query(BuchungSystem!A2:AZ,"Select C, F, H, I, J, K, L where Q = "& $B$10)
```

**formula2**

```
=arrayformula({{"MWST ",""}} & QUERY(query(BuchungSystem!A2:AZ,"Select M, N, L where Q = "& $B$10),"SELECT Col1*100, SUM(Col2) GROUP BY Col1, Col3 LABEL SUM(Col2) '' , Col1*100 ''"))
```

and the result is shown as below

[image]

I need to combine 2 ranges since the number of rows in table1 keeps changing and so in table2. Since both are query formulas, they would not expand if the underlying cells have data. To avoid such issues, I am thinking both tables can be joined together with 2 empty lines between tables.

I have tried to join the query result ranges using {formula1;formula2} but it gives me an error since both tables have differing columns. How can I merge the tables one below other?

Comment: Could you please share a sample sheet. [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Answer (score 1):

Mind sharing an example sheet?  Here is a quick example of how to include empty columns to make the ranges equal in column size.

```
={{QUERY(G1:K4,"SELECT G,H,I,J,K")};{"","","","",SUM(QUERY(G1:K4,"SELECT G,H,I,J,K"))}}
```

If you use 6 columns in one range and only 2 in the next, then you need 4 empty columns in the second `{}` so their sizes remain the same.